# Why I got the same time in for statement of dos-batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I write a batch file to get the start time of cmd in for statement:

```
for /L %%i in (1,1,3) do (
echo %%i
echo "traceroute %%i start at %date% %time%" >tr%%i.txt
adb shell "/data/local/traceroute smtp.163.com" 2>&1 >>tr%%i.txt
)
```

but got the same time in 3 result file:

```
"traceroute 1 start at 2013/03/27 周三 15:48:47.12"

"traceroute 2 start at 2013/03/27 周三 15:48:47.12" 

"traceroute 3 start at 2013/03/27 周三 15:48:47.12"
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

A `FOR` loop is `parsed` from the `FOR` to its final closing parenthesis (ie. `ALL` of the codesegment you posted. At this time, **ANY** `%var%` will be replaced by the `THEN-CURRENT` (ie. PARSE-TIME) value of the variable. **THEN** the code is executed.

Hence `%date% %time%` were replaced by their values at the time the command was PARSED.

You can overcome the problem in at least three ways:

1/ with DELAYED EXPANSION, invoked by a `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` instruction, when %var% STILL shows the PARSE-TIME value, but `!var!` shows the RUN-TIME value
2/ Indirect expansion by CALLing `%%var%%`
3/ Use a subroutine or external batchfile

Try this code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR %%i IN (1 2 3) DO (
ECHO START of run %%i
ECHO using ^!time^! : !time! - PARSE TIME was %time%
CALL ECHO using CALL %%%%TIME%%%% : %%TIME%%
CALL :report
timeout /t 5
ECHO using ^!time^! : !time!
CALL ECHO using CALL %%%%TIME%%%% : %%TIME%%
CALL :report
ECHO END of run %%i
ECHO.
)
GOTO :eof

:report
ECHO :report says TIME is %TIME%
GOTO :eof
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use delayed expansion `!variable!`s:

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /L %%i in (1,1,3) do (
echo %%i
echo "traceroute %%i start at !date! !time!" >tr%%i.txt
adb shell "/data/local/traceroute smtp.163.com" 2>&1 >>tr%%i.txt
)
```